# htaccess rewrite url rule for folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

****** Already answered *******

I am currently trying to rewrite urls as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    article.php?title=$1    [NC,L]
```

This will take a url such as www.mydomain.com/lemons and rewrite to www.mydomain.com/article.php?title=lemons

That's all good and what I want.

The actual article on lemons is then pulled from a database and displayed at that url.

Within the article I then have some tags. For example, the lemons article might have the tags: fruit, yellow

The url for each tag would look like this:

```
 www.example.com/tag/fruit

 www.example.com/tag/yellow
```

I have added the following to my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule    ^tag/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    tag.php?tag=$1    [NC,L]
```

So, now when I click on the tag of fruit I am taken to: www.mydomain.com/tag/fruit

This will then pull a list of all articles from the database with the tag of fruit

Any urls within this page are displayed as http://www.example.com/tag/**newarticle**

e.g. http://www.example.com/tag/apple

However, I need http://www.example.com/apple

Many thanks

Comment: im not sure I understand what you are asking...

Comment: You need to keep `tag` to differentiate between your rewrites. if you remove tag and use `www.mydomain.com/fruit` how will apache know not to use your first rule and internally direct to article.php? You can't have **both** articles and tags as a subfolder pretty url.

Comment: my apologies @Panama Jack - update query now

Answer (score 1):

I feel so stupid!

I just needed to add a / to the beginning of the article link.